# Is it possible to whitelist a specific IP that belongs to a banned network?

Tags: fail2ban, whitelist

I need to whitelist a specific IP that belongs to a fail2ban banned network. Does ignoreip option works in this case? How can I solve otherwise? I've to manage directly with iptables for this IP? 
Another question: how I can see the status of the jail ignoreip list at runtime? fail2ban-client status does not show this information neighter I can find the whitelisted IP from iptables -S.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the *ignoreip* option will work. No IPs listed there will ever be banned by fail2ban. You can use single IPs or a CIDR mask.